# JavaScript Update not working properly(some time its happen) in sqlite

Tags: javascript, android, html, sqlite, cordova

```
function update() {
         //function onDeviceReady() {
         debugger;

         var fav = "";


         //var a = hdn1.split(",");
         fav = document.getElementById("hdn1").value + ",";


         fav += document.getElementById("hdn2").value + ",";

         fav += document.getElementById("hdn3").value;
         var itm = fav.split(",");
         //alert(itm);
         var strgfalseItem;
         var strgTrueitem;
         var trueitem = Array();
         var falseitem = Array();
         var j = 0;
         var k = 0;
         for (i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
             if (itm[i] == "checked") {

                 trueitem[j] = i + 155;
                 if (j == 0) {
                     strgTrueitem = trueitem[j] + ",";
                 }
                 else {
                     strgTrueitem += trueitem[j] + ",";

                 }
                 j = j + 1;
             }
             else {
                 falseitem[k] = i + 155;
                 if (k == 0) {
                     strgfalseItem = falseitem[k] + ",";
                 }
                 else {
                     strgfalseItem += falseitem[k] + ",";
                 }
                 k = k + 1;
             }


         }
         //strgTrueitem = trueitem;
         // strgfalseItem = falseitem;
         strgTrueitem = strgTrueitem.substring(0, strgTrueitem.length - 1);
         strgfalseItem = strgfalseItem.substring(0, strgfalseItem.length - 1);



         var db = window.openDatabase("Hadith", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
         db.transaction(function (tx) {
             //tx.executeSql('UPDATE RenderDetails SET favorite=1 WHERE nodeId=157', [], function (tx, res) {
             tx.executeSql('UPDATE RenderDetails SET Favorite= 1  WHERE nodeId IN (' + strgTrueitem + ');', [], function (tx, res) {
                 //alert("Form Submitted Successfully...");
             }, function (e) {

                 alert("Error processing SQL: " + err);
             });

             tx.executeSql('UPDATE RenderDetails SET Favorite=0 WHERE nodeId IN (' + strgfalseItem + ');', [], function (tx, res) {



             }, function (e) {
                 alert("Error processing SQL: " + err);
             });



         });


         window.location.reload(history.go(-1));









         //alert("Update Successfully");


     }
 </script>
```

This is a android application, using in Java script and HTML using sqlite data base

The above function is update sqlite Database but its only happen some  time after updating done go back to previous age. Please help me.